# Numpy convolution (convolve) seems to produce a huge error on complex signals

Tags: python, numpy, convolution, dot-product

I have noticed that `numpy.convolve` produces strange results on sufficiently complex signals. Here is a simple test example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal

def conv_np(x, win):
    return np.convolve(x, win, 'valid')

def conv_dot(x, win):
    Z = np.asarray( [x[cnt:cnt+win.shape[0]] for cnt in range(x.shape[0]-win.shape[0]+1)] )
    return np.dot(Z, win)

# test 1
x = np.repeat([0., 1., 0.], 300)
win = signal.hamming(50)

plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot( conv_np(x, win) - conv_dot(x, win) )

# test 2
x = np.random.random(size=(10000,))
win = x[4000:5000]

plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot( conv_np(x, win) - conv_dot(x, win) )

plt.show()
```

And here's the result:
[image: Difference between numpy and dot product implementation of convolution.]

The plots show the difference between `numpy.convolve` and direct implementation of convolution using dot produce. The top plot is for a simple signal and window (a step and a Hann window). The bottom plot is for a random signal and the window being just a portion of this signal.

So there is almost no difference between the dot product and `numpy` implementations of the convolution for a simple signal/window, yet there is an enormous difference for complex signal/window.

Since dot product implementation can be considered a ground truth, I interpret this difference as `numpy`'s error. Please let me know if I am wrong or if there is a way to make `numpy` produce the same results as dot product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To properly implement convolution with a dot product [you need to reflect the kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Visual_explanation). If you redefine `conv_dot` as:

```
def conv_dot(x, win):
    Z = [x[cnt:cnt+win.size] for cnt in range(x.size-win.size+1)]
    return np.dot(Z, win[::-1])  # the [::-1] is the only real change
```

You will find that the errors are now negligible as expected, at most `2e-13` in a trial run I did with your second example.